# CakePHP: Search BETWEEN datetimes and validate form

Tags: mysql, cakephp, validation, between

I'm stuck with this. My own skills aren't enough to solve this myself.

I have a form with these fields:

- `PLACE_ID`
- `START_DATE` (`DATETIME`)
- `END_DATE` (`DATETIME`)

What I try to achieve:

- If there are already bookings in database **in the same time range,
  in the same place**, the submit will fail.

So, the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings
WHERE place_id=".$_POST['placeId']."
AND('".$_POST['startDate']."'
BETWEEN  start_date 
AND end_date
OR '".$_POST['endDate']."'
BETWEEN start_date
AND end_date)"
```

If this returns `NULL`, the submit will success. How to get this working with CakePHP? Please, help...

Comment: you are using very high risk to sql injections ,your code will be hacked in 2 seconds

Comment: The search query was just an example. Just don't know how to convert it as CakePHP way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a separation of logic perspective, I think this should be handled in your controller. Building from Ollie Jones advice, upon post-back from the user's browser, you should do something like the following:

```
$this->Booking->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Booking.start_date BETWEEN' => array($new_start_date, $new_end_date), 'Booking.end_date BETWEEN' => array($new_start_date, $new_end_date))
```

`$new_start_date` should be set to `$this->data['Booking']['start_date']` and the same goes for `$new_end_date`. The answer just starts to look messy otherwise!

If the query returns nothing then you can go ahead and save your new booking. If there are bookings, you should advise your user accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution I needed. However, `BETWEEN` selects also the time that is equal. So, I think I need to use comparison that it selects only the datetimes that are between the time range, not the ones that are equal to `start_date` or equal to `end_date`. Do someone have an example how this could be done?

Comment: `BETWEEN` selects an inclusive or an exclusive range dependent on your database. If you want a guaranteed exclusive range then you should use `'Booking.start_date >' => $start_date, 'Booking.end_date <' => $start_date`.

Comment: Big thanks to you! It seems working now. I'm using code as follows: `$conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array(
     'Booking.place_id' => $this->data['Booking']['place_id'],
     'Booking.start_date <' => $this->data['Booking']['end_date'],
     'Booking.end_date >' => $this->data['Booking']['start_date']
    )
   );
   $bookings = $this->Booking->find( 'all', $conditions );
   $this->set( 'bookings', $bookings );`

Comment: I'm glad to help. To echo what others have said here, try to avoid executing SQL queries directly in your application as it reduces the risk of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Take advantage of CakePHP's excellent Object Relational Mapping (ORM) as it keeps everything nice, tidy, and safe!

Answer (score 1):

The comments warning you about SQL injection are correct.

Using `BETWEEN` for `DATETIME` data type search is problematical. I'm not sure this is your problem, but it might be.

Consider a `DATETIME` value of, say, `'2013-04-13 11:00:00'`  You'd think this would be `BETWEEN '2013-04-13' AND '2013-04-13'`, but it isn't, because it's after `'2013-04-13 00:00:00'`.

One of the unpleasant problems with this use of `BETWEEN` is that single day ranges don't work.

What you need for a date range match is

```
      date_to_test >= start_date
  AND date_to_test < end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```